# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \arctan(\ln x) = \frac{-\pi}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to figure out how I can solve $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \arctan(\ln x)$ without looking at Desmos. I know it equals $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ but I am not sure why.

I thought I could solve this sort of problem by finding the intersection of the ranges of both $\ln x$ and $\arctan x$.

In other words, $[0, \infty) \cap [\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] = [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Since 0 is the lowest bound, I would put zero as the answer.

Except, I know that's wrong.

*How can I find out why $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \arctan(\ln x) = \frac{-\pi}{2}$ without looking at Desmos?*

Comment: Do you know what $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln x$ is?

Comment: @MartinR I would assume $-\infty$? or $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln(x) = - \infty$$

and

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} \arctan(x) = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. Thanks!